# How To open Application from the Link in the message which is sent by the branch.io?

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I create deep link for my application which is register on branch.io . I sent the url using message. When I clicked on that link it is redirecting me to the google Playstore even though I have application installed on my phone.

My Intent Filter :

```
            <data android:scheme="finaldeeplinking" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

URI Scheme on branch.io :   finaldeeplinking://

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Branch default before a few days ago was to only try to open up the app if the service knew 100% that the app was installed, which was defined by whether it had seen a browser cookie matched to a Branch-tracked app session. Otherwise, the link would 307 redirect to the Play Store URL.

However, they recently changed the default to 'Always open up the app' based on the needs of their developers. You likely need to update your setting. You can toggle this switch on the [link settings dashboard](https://dashboard.branch.io/#/settings/link). Make sure that you toggle this checkbox to checked:

[image]